# Coxph function - missing coefficient

Tags: r, statistics

I am working on some survival analysis lately and I got an error, which I am not sure how to fix. I am working on 6 different age groups and 4 different scenarios. I wanted to calculate p-value for each age group in a given scenario (so in total 24 pvalues). My code looks like this:

```
for (scenario in scenario_list) {
  df_scenario_filtered <- df %>% filter(str_detect(scenario_group, scenario))
  
  cox_model <- coxph(Surv(OSTM, OSSTAT) ~ AGE_GROUP, data = df_scenario_filtered)
  
  p_values <- summary(cox_model)$coefficients[, "Pr(>|z|)"]
  
  print(paste("Scenario Name:", scenario))
  print(p_values)
}
```

I got the results but they are not complete. For each scenario one p-value from the same age group is missing. Why could be the possible reason? Data is split equally for each group so that shouldn't be the issue.

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Are you sure you don't have an overaparmeterised model?  (If your output includes an intercept term, you almost certainly do.)  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67020730/why-summary-a-linear-model-in-r-does-not-show-all-the-needed-levels/67021012#67021012) for more explanation.

Comment: The AGE_GROUP is almost certainly a categorical variable and so the estimate for the lowest level would typically be included in the coefficient for the "Intercept" term. There are many similar questions on StackOverflow. Bottom line: People migrating from other software systems with different conventions for contrasts may experience cognitive dissonance when first encountering R's default of "treatment contrasts". If you read the nominated duplicates and search on those terms and fail to find a complete explanation, then post the results of your search and explain what is unclear.